# Can't get input radio selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck with complicated html structure. And also can't change it as it is come from server side(outside).

I am trying to get input radio selected value. But can't.

Following what i have tried But, as i am not much powerful can't solution. And also don't know what i am trying is right Or Wrong.

As there is multiple elements i have tried with `children` And also there are other radio inputs in my html markup.

```js
console.log($('.ClearanceItem')[0].rows[0].cells[1].children[0].children[1].children[0].children[1].children.find('input[name="myRadio"]:checked').val());
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="ClearanceItem">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="Mobile">Clear
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="2" name="Mobile">Pending
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="3" name="Mobile">Waived Off
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="1" name="Computer">text1
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="2" name="Computer">text2
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="3" name="Computer">text3
                </label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: `console.log($('.ClearanceItem :radio[name="Computer"]:checked').val()`

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla There are many input with radio

Comment: You can differentiate it with name. can't you do that?

Comment: In your example you have to use  $('input[name="Computer"]:checked').val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()` will return the selected radio.

You can also specify which form the radio is a child of by using the following example:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

Comment: first line is ok. simply change 'radioName' to the real name of your input - Mobile/Computer

Comment: Second line is not relevant if your radio buttons have different names. you could use it though if you wrap both in different forms giving each its own id and change 'myForm' to the desired form id