# Input type radio data value only shows one when trying to get all selected input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I'm trying to make a quiz for myself and I want the data values of the selected radio buttons and the data value of them. So I can send them to a php file as an array or object.

This is my code:

```
let frm = $('#form');

    $('input[value="finished"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').data('value'));

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: "ajax/quiz.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

            },
        }).done(function (data) {

        });
    });
```

Does anyone know why it only shows one? Because I have been searching for a while and a lot of people recommend this option.

[Can't get input radio selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370412/cant-get-input-radio-selected-value)

I also tried this:
[How to get the selected radio button’s value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618504/how-to-get-the-selected-radio-button-s-value)

But it still shows me one data value.

Comment: As it seems, every time you change the page, the previous `input` fields are removed. Is that the case? Make sure they are hidden by CSS and not removed by JS

Comment: Also pay attention that `$('input[type=radio]:checked')` is a collection. So you should better check its length instead of using `data` method on it, because that `data` method will yield the last one's data

Comment: They get a display: none; but the elements stays. When i click the previous button the answer I selected is still there and selected, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Youre right, the length value equals 2, but how do i get those values?

Comment: Do your `input` fields have a `name` attribute? If they don't, `frm.serialize()` will not include them.

Comment: They do have a input and a name, the serialize is not the problem, i need something that replaces serialize because that doesnt give me the data value @pooria

Comment: Do you have to use `data-value` instead of `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on saving the values inside `dataset` (`<input data-value="" />`) you can do it this way:

```js
const values = $('input[type=radio]:checked')
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).data('value')
  })
  .get();
```

Now, `values` is an array of all `data-value` values in selected radio boxes.

You can read more about `jQuery`'s `map` here: https://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. I show below two wrong ways and two correct ways:

```js
$(function() {
    let frm = $('#form');

    $('input[value="finished"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /*console.log($('input[type=radio]:checked').data('value'));

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: "ajax/quiz.php",
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

            },
        }).done(function (data) {

        });*/
        let output = document.getElementById("output");
        let val = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        let data = $('input[type=radio]:checked').data('value');
        let serialized = frm.serialize();
        let accumulated = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked')].map((item) => `${item.name}=${item.value}`).join("&");
        output.innerHTML += `<p>val(): ${val}</p>`;
        output.innerHTML += `<p>data('value'): ${data}</p>`;
        output.innerHTML += `<p>serialized: ${serialized}</p>`; //works
        output.innerHTML += `<p>accumulated: ${accumulated}</p>`; //works
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1_1">
    <input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1_2">
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer2_1">
    <input type="radio" name="question2" value="answer2_2">
    <input type="submit" value="finished">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```